# Accessing a VPN from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco

I am trying to access my schools VPN but it isn't working.  I haven't used it in awhile but I followed the same procedure and it isn't working.

I installed Cisco's Anytime Connect, I configured the VPN:

I put the gateway as `https://sslvpn.uvm.edu` and then my user name and password.

However, whenever I try to connect, it says:

```
The vpn connection failed because the vpn service failed to start.
```

Am I missing something during set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing open connect corrects the problem.

Open connect establishes the connection to the vpn.